# If $\text{avg}(A+B) = \text{avg}(A'+B')$ and $\text{avg}(A)<\text{avg}(A')$, is $\text{avg}(B)>\text{avg}(B')$?

Tags: mean

I have been struggling with this for a while. In my mind, it is very obvious but I feel like I am missing something so I cannot argue it mathematically.

Suppose we have four sets of datapoints: $A, B, A', B'$ such that $n(A)+n(B)=n(A')+n(B')$

If we know that $\text{avg}(A+B) = \text{avg}(A'+B')$ and that $\text{avg}(A)<\text{avg}(A')$, does that guarantee that $\text{avg}(B)>\text{avg}(B')$?

Comment: Use linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. You can refute the guess by a counterexample:

$$
A = \{1,2\}, B = \{3,4,5\}
$$

$$
A' = \{1,2,3,4\}, B'=\{5\} 
$$

$\text{avg}(A+B) = \text{avg}(A' + B') = 3$ and $n(A) + n(B) = n(A') + n(B') = 5$ and $\text{avg}(A) = 1.5 < \text{avg}(A') = 2.5$, But $\text{avg}(B) = 4 \not> \text{avg}(B') = 5$.

It depends on the size of these sets and you can't say a general term in this way.

Moreover, if $n(A) > n(A')$, there will be a counterexample as well:

$$ A = \{3,4,5\}, B = \{1,2\}$$
$$ A' = \{5\}, B' = \{1,2,3,4\}$$

$n(A)=3 > n(A')= 1$, $\text{avg}(A) = 4 < \text{avg}(A') = 5$, But $\text{avg}(B) = 1.5 \not> \text{avg}(B') = 2.5$.

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample.

If we are adding an additional condition: $n(A) > n(A')$ (so $n(B) < n(B')$, would that be enough to argue that $avg(B) > avg(B')$ ?

Comment: You seem to interpret "$+$" (addition) as "$\cup$" (union), which to many readers is unexpected because it is unusual.

Comment: @whuber Yes. What does "$+$" mean between two sets other than union?

Comment: Elementwise addition.  If "set" really means "batch of data," this could be vector additoin, but generally one can add two sets of numbers by forming all sums where one number is taken from one of the sets and the other addend is from the other set.

Comment: @whuber Even for two sets with different sizes (as size of sets mentioned in the question)?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  This is a common operation and fairly common notation.  Even more confusingly, "$+$" in a set context (when the sets don't necessarily have numbers as elements) often refers to symmetric difference.

Comment: @whuber However, if you mean the Minkowski sum, I think it's not the aim of the OP as here talking about datasets, not a geometrical meaning.

Comment: I do not mean that.  I am describing very generally understood meanings of the symbol "$+$" when applied to pairs of sets.

Comment: @whuber I see. However, we should change it in the question as OP is talking about the union.

Comment: @gdsquare please see the update.